# Div Refresh Working Only Once

Tags: javascript, load, refresh

I have a button set up to refresh a certain div when it's clicked. Problem is that it only works once.

The div that I need refreshing when the button is clicked:

```
<div id="refresh">

    <?php include('space.php'); ?>

</div>
```

The script to refresh the div:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#go").click(function() {
        jQuery("#refresh").load("space.php");
    });
});
```

and the contents of space.php:

```
 <?php

    /* get disk space free (in bytes) */
    $df = disk_free_space("/home");
    /* and get disk space total (in bytes)  */
    $dt = disk_total_space("/home");
    /* now we calculate the disk space used (in bytes) */
    $du = $dt - $df;
    /* percentage of disk used - this will be used to also set the width % of the progress bar */
    $dp = sprintf('%.2f',($du / $dt) * 100);

    /* and we formate the size from bytes to MB, GB, etc. */
    $df = formatSize($df);
    $du = formatSize($du);
    $dt = formatSize($dt);

    function formatSize( $bytes )
    {
            $types = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB' );
            for( $i = 0; $bytes >= 1024 && $i < ( count( $types ) -1 ); $bytes /= 1024, $i++ );
                    return( round( $bytes, 2 ) . " " . $types[$i] );
    }

    ?>



        <table class='ipb_table' cellspacing='1'>  

                <tr>

                    <td class='row2' colspan='2'>

                        <div class='progress'>

                                <div class='prgbar'></div>

                        </div>

                    </td>

                <tr>


                    <td class='row2'>

                        Disk Space:

                    </td>


                    <td class='row2'>

                        <?php echo "$dt"; ?>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class='row2'>

                        Free: 

                    </td>

                    <td class='row2'>

                        <?php echo "$df"; ?>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class='row2'>

                        Used:

                    </td>

                    <td class='row2'>

                        <?php echo "$du"; ?>

                    </td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td class='row2' colspan='2' align='center'>

<a class='ipsButton' id='go'>Refresh<a>

                    </td>

                </tr>                           

        </table>
```

Comment: Paste the code in the question instead of in a fiddle, as the code isn't testable in the fiddle anyway.

Comment: Well, on JS Fiddle the `<?php /*...*/ ?>` isn't going to do anything, plus you're trying to run jQuery under MooTools.

Comment: Code added instead of fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `<?php include('space.php'); ?>`
Jquery is fine.Test this out

```
    jQuery(function() {
    var i=1;
    jQuery("#go").click(function() {
        jQuery("#refresh").html(i);
        i++;
    });
});​
```

[jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaAG3/2/)

Make sure `space.php` is on the same server. And second thing is that `.load` is not the replace of `php include`. Do this with `jQuery Ajax`

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may work.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("#go").on('click', function() {
        jQuery("#refresh").load("space.php");
    });
});​
```